# How add or merge duplicate rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a data frame with over 2000 rows, but in the first column, there are a number of duplicates. I want to add up the data in each duplicate together. An example of the data is seen below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJENT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case, I think this is what you are expecting which will squeeze the duplicate rows and returns single row and its sum

```
df2 = df.groupby('Player').sum()
print(df2)
```

You can also explicitly specify on which column you wanted to do a `sum()` operation. The below example applies the sum on the Gls column which is in the image you provided.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Player')['Gls'].sum()
print(df2)
```

Hope this helps your case, if not please feel free to comment. Thanks